# Procedural Hash Function

Tags: hyperlink, procedural, noise, perlin-noise

I am wondering what is the best hash function for procedural textures, especially perlin noise. I know about the PRNG posted on [this page](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm), but [this](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=459087) claims that it is not a good PRNG

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the "Mersenne Twister with improved initialization" PRNG for my implementation perlin-noise and other procedural textures (http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html)
It is very efficient and the randomness is very good.